# Expression of generated column 'birthday_filter' contains a disallowed function

Tags: mysql-5.7, computed-column

I want to add a generate column using this sql command:

```
ALTER TABLE spark_user_demo 
ADD COLUMN birthday_filter bigint
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(birthday, '%Y年%m月%d日'))) STORED;
```

but the MySQL 5.7 database shows error like this:

```
Expression of generated column 'birthday_filter' contains a disallowed function.
```

this is the database DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `spark_user_demo` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `headimgurl` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sex` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `zodiac` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `birthday` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `constellation` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `height` double NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `weight` double NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `census_register` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `marital_status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `education` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `occupation` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `income` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `hobby_tag` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `phone` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `wechat_number` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `id_number` varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '',
  `car` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `car_brand` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `car_model` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `house` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `house_area` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `house_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `invest` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `invest_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `invest_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `children` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `only_child` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `place_residence` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `job_nature` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `parent_relation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `smoke` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `drink` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `updated_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1052 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

what should I do to fix this problem? I run this command it could work:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date('2002年05月11日', '%Y年%m月%d日'));
```

I also tried this way:

```
ALTER TABLE spark_user_demo 
ADD COLUMN birthday_filter_diff varchar(128)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,str_to_date(birthday, '%Y年%m月%d日'),now())) STORED;
```

still did not work. As you can see, they store the user birthday as a string that I want to query the user by the age, I want to generate a bigint type of birthday or int type of user age, what should I do? how to generate a bigint birthday or int age that I could filter usign `>` and `<`?

Comment: If you get rid of the `STORED` keyword, does it work?

Comment: I removed the sorted keyword, it did not work.@J.D.

Comment: I assumed MySQL *may* let you create the virtual column if you didn't persist it with the `STORED` keyword, but even that's not allowed apparently. [This is your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37176579/5059085) most likely though. You can't use non-deterministic functions when generating a virtual column.

Comment: then what should I do with my situation? @J.D. any better way that I could do a user filter?

Comment: It's likely happening because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is considered a non-deterministic function in MySQL. You could either just generate the virtual column on `str_to_date(birthday, '%Y年%m月%d日')` and when you `SELECT` that column you can then apply the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function and logic you want to it or you can try *manually* computing the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` (not sure if possible). Or you can just store an actual column called birthdaySeconds and your application layer computes and fills it in. I'm not an expert on MySQL so unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to write an actual answer.